# WLST: cannot call edit functions when you are not in the edit tree

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I'm trying to run the following WLST script

```
import java.lang
import os
import string

# 1 - Connecting to the Destination
connect(username,password,server_url)

edit()

# 2 - Security Realm
print ""
print "================== Seucrity Realm ==================="
startEdit()
serverConfig()

ap = cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupAuthenticationProvid
er('DefaultAuthenticator')

print "Create group " + user_group
ap.createGroup(user_group, user_group)

print "Craete user " + user_name
ap.createUser(user_name, user_pass, user_name)

print "Add user " + user_name + " to group " + user_group
ap.addMemberToGroup(user_group, user_name)

print "Create global role " + user_role

rm = cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupRoleMapper('XACMLRol
eMapper')
rm.createRole(None, user_role, None)
rm.setRoleExpression(None, user_role, 'Grp(' + user_group + ')')

# Save, activate and exit
# ==========================
print ""
save()
activate()
exit()
```

But get the error

```
No stack trace available.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/u01/oracle/security-realm-config.py", line 40, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 510, in save
  File "<iostream>", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing save : Cannot call Edit functions
 when you are not in the Edit tree.
```

The script still works, but why it prints this error, and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "serverConfig()" line. You switch out of your edit context to a "new" mbean tree, which is not in editeable state. Either move your serverConfig() line to before the edit() command, or remove it altogether as the serverConfig tree is the default tree after connecting anyways.